# Onenote crashes every few minutes

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Onenote crashes few minutes after starting it. Three message are shown then, something like:
"The application doesn't work anymore. It will search for a solution."
"Microsoft tries to restart the application. This can last few minutes."
"Application will be restarted"
After automatic restarting it seems to work, but after few minutes the problem happens again and again and again.

An extract of event-viewer message:
Faulting Application Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\ONENOTE.EXE
Exception Code: e06d7363
Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll

Following approaches to solve the problem were unsuccessful:

- Reinstall MS Office

Comment: Sign out of your Microsoft Account.  Does this still happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the cache (described here: http://onenote-tips.com/troubleshooting.html) solved the problem.